# Redirect all traffic to https://www using a .conf file (httpd/Apache2)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want the following addresses to redirect to `https://www.foobar.com` :

```
 - http://www.foobar.com
 - http://foobar.com
 - https://foobar.com
```

I've tried using this but it doesn't work:

etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://www.foobar.com$1
```